# primefaces autocomplete validation issue

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have a problem with p:autocomplete: When the validation fails on any other field I miss the input of the autocomplete. What can I do to avoid this?

I am using prime faces 3.5 with mojarra 2.1.18. This is the code:

```
<h:outputLabel for="employmentTitle" value="Dienstbezeichnung:" />
<p:autoComplete id="employmentTitle" minQueryLength="3" maxResults="20" value="#{contactManagedBean.contactPerson.employmentTitle}" label="Dienstbezeichnung" var="e" itemValue="#{e}"
    itemLabel="#{e.value}" effect="fade" completeMethod="#{contactManagedBean.completeEmploymentTitles}" converter="#{keyValueTableConverter}">
    <f:validator validatorId="contactPersonTypeFacesValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="contactPerson" value="#{contactManagedBean.contactPerson}" />
    <f:attribute name="personTypeComponent" value="#{personTypeComponent}" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

Edited:

Sorry my fault. My KeyValueTableConverter missed the call to the service bean like this:

```
/**
 * 
 * make an object from web request param
 */
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String param) {

    KeyValueTable k = null;

    try {

        k = serviceBean.getValuesById(Long.parseLong(param));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error("Error while making an object from web request param: " + param + " keyvaluetable: " + k, e);
    }

    return k;
}
```